# When i update my ADT plugin for Android i get run android lint ,what are adavantages of it to use it for android project?

Tags: android, android-lint

Every One Here

When i update my ADT plugin to ADT 16 i get One new (Tool)thing which is run android Lint when i run it after select my android project it give me more 550 warning  related to project for android .should i have to follow advise by Lint for my resource like String.xml and some of layout use in my activity .

For Knowing more about  Lint i refer this tips here is  [Click here](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint)
It also Give me Warning Like Below :

Hardcoded string "AnyThing", should use @string resource

So what i think is Lint will help for resource problem in android.

If you have more thing about android lint then let me known .

and what should i do will This xml for lint and where should i put this xml in project root or any other directory.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
</lint>
```

and i also getting  This Warning "[Accessibility] missing `contentDescription` attribute on image" for `ImageView`. while using android lint

I think by giving following things like below To Images:

```
 android:contentDescription="@string/desc"
```

This defines text that briefly describes content of the view. This property is used primarily for accessibility. Since some views do not have textual representation this attribute can be used for providing such.

Non-textual widgets like `ImageViews` and `ImageButtons` should use the `contentDescription` attribute to specify a textual description of the widget such that screen readers and other accessibility tools can adequately describe the user interface.

Comment: many words with wrong (first) capital character. It makes us hard to read. Could you please edit it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried lint just for fun. What I can say. It's a type of static analysis tool that is developed specifically for Android. Thus, a developer of Android applications can run automatic static tests across his/her code.

You can run lint in Eclipse simply pressing on button in the panel (this button in my case is near the button of AVD Manager. After that Eclipse opens a window where all violations of lint rules are displayed. You can double click on the error and correct it. As a static analysis tool it can have false positives.

The lint tool has been already supplied with the number of embedded rules. You can read about them on [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) lint page.

As for lint xml file, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: Not at all )) Hope this was useful for you!

Comment: yeah ADT 16 add Lint which ready Use Full To increase in layout and Resource use in android project ,it really help to find non usable String From String.xml which really a +1 Point For Me.